# How to remove the HTTPS requirement for SAML configuration in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

The application I am using with WSO2 is running under HTTP in a development environment.  A cookie with samesite set to strict will soon be lost due to browser security udpates during the scheme change to WSO2 (HTTP to HTTPS).  This cookie is required for a particular piece of functionality upon the redirect to the app I'm using.

I'd like to test SAML configuration in a non-HTTPS secured dev or testing environment with this app but cannot because I can't figure out how to disable HTTPS for the samlsso endpoint.

I've found tutorials on how to do this for the admin console, but that does not apply to other endpoints. I am using WSO2 version 6.0.0 at the moment but can update if necessary. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Identity Server does not support serving HTTP requests. Some requests might work, but it is not fully supported.

The recommendation is to use HTTPS even for internal calls between LB/proxy and WSO2IS.